# laravel notifications not storing into my database plus error

Tags: laravel, notifications, pusher

i couldn't store the notification into my notification table inside my database,
i was trying to make notification every time there is a new Post  how can i make this work.

**Error:**

[image]

**Notification:**

```
use Queueable;
public $post;


public function __construct()
{

}


public function via($notifiable)
{
    return ['database'];
}


public function toDatabase($notifiable)
{
    return [
        'title' => $this->post->title,
    ];
}


public function toArray($notifiable)
{
    return [

    ];
}
```

}

**Post Controller:**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{

    $this->validate($request, [
        'title'=>'required|max:100',
        'body' =>'required',
        ]);

    $title = $request['title'];
    $body = $request['body'];

    $post = Post::create($request->only('title', 'body'));


   Auth::user()->notify(new NotifyPost($post));


    return redirect()->route('posts.index')
        ->with('flash_message', 'Article,
         '. $post->title.' created');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to inject the post within the construct, or else it never gets resolved.

```
protected $post;

public function __construct(Post $post)
{
    $this->post = $post;
}
```

Comment: Please try my suggestion. If it still doesn't work, then let me know the error.